# What happens when $f(t)=rect(\frac{x-10}{2})rect(\frac{x}{2}) $ ? Which takes priority?

Tags: graphing-functions

> What happens when $f(t)=rect(\frac{x-10}{2})rect(\frac{x}{2}) $ ? Which takes priority?

The first function occurs between $9<x<11$ while the second rect occurs when $-1<x<1$. What exactly happens in this function?

EDIT:

Rect is defined as:

$$-\frac12<x<\frac12: 1 $$
$$else: 0$$

Comment: What is "rect"?

Comment: It is impossible for both terms in the multiplication to be non-zero as there is no such $x$ which satisfies both inequalities. Therefore $f$ is $0$. I think you might have some sort of confusion as you talk about 'priority' when none exists and this term makes little sense/is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply point by point. You will see that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on multiplying point by point?

Comment: First, I believe it is $f(x)$ instead of $f(t)$. By point-by-point multiplication, I mean that for any $x$ evaluate rect((x-10)/2) and rect(x/2) and multiply them. For $-1 < x <1$, the first rect() is zero, and for other values of $x$ the second rect() is zero.